# How could I save user entry inside a state in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, redux, react-redux

I need to fire the action to update `storyTextValue` inside `StoryTextReducer` so I can use it as `this.props.storyTextValue` in `SearchArticle`.

In other words, in `CreateArticle` upon the user typing in `<textarea>` followed by clicking `Submit`, I want whatever they've typed in to be stored in `storyTextValue` which would allow me to use `this.props.storyTextValue` in `SearchArticle` to display the text.

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve this?

Here's `CreateArticle`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import * as actionType from "../../store/actions/actions";

class CreateArticle extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({storyTextValue: event.target.storyTextValue});
        this.props.storyTextValueRedux(event.target.storyTextValue);
    }

    handleStoryText = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    onSubmit = () => {
        if(this.props.storyTextValue === "") {
            alert("Please enter the value and then click submit");
        } else {
            alert("Article saved " + '\n' + this.props.storyTextValue);
        }
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.props.cityCodeValue} type="text" placeholder="city code"/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="author name"/>
                    <textarea value={this.props.storyTextValue} onChange={this.handleStoryText} rows="2" cols="25" />
                    <button type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={() => this.onSubmit()}>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        articleIdValue: state.articleIdValue.articleIdValue,
        storyTextValue: state.storyTextValue.storyTextValue
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        articleIdValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.ARTICLE_ID_VALUE, value}),
        storyTextValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.STORY_VALUE, value})
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateArticle);
```

Here's `SearchArticle`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actionType from '../../store/actions/actions';

class SearchArticle extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            flag: false
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        this.props.CityCodeReducerRedux(event.target.value);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        this.setState({flag: true});
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    displayName = () => {
        if(this.props.cityCodeValue === "nyc" || this.props.articleIdValue === 1) {
            return(
                <div>
                    <p>author name: {this.props.authorNameValue}</p>
                    <p>article text: {this.props.storyTextValue}</p> {/* want to display story text here */}
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.props.cityCodeValue} type="text" placeholder="city code"/>
                    <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.props.articleIdValue} placeholder="article id"/>
                    <button onClick={() => this.displayName}  value="Search">Submit</button>
                    {this.state.flag ? this.displayName() : null}
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        cityCodeValue: state.cityCodeValue.cityCodeValue,
        authorNameValue: state.authorNameValue.authorNameValue,
        articleIdValue: state.articleIdValue.articleIdValue,
        storyTextValue: state.storyTextValue.storyTextValue
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        CityCodeReducerRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.CITY_CODE_VALUE, value}),
        articleIdValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.ARTICLE_ID_VALUE, value})
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchArticle);
```

Here's `StoryTextReducer`:

```
import * as actionType from '../store/actions/actions';

const initialState = {
    storyTextValue: ''
};

const StoryTextReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionType.STORY_VALUE:
            return {
                ...state,
                storyTextValue: action.value
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default StoryTextReducer;
```

Comment: Is this code even working? Looks like you are also tracking this.state.storyTextValue for no reason? Anyway, make sure you're updating the store and every component subscribed to the changes in that particular state tree should receive updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `handleSubmit` of `CreateArticle` please `console.log(event.target.storyTextValue)`.... i would think it is undefined. I think you would prefer `this.props.storyTextValueRedux(event.target.value);`

Comment: I did the `console.log` , yes it's undefined.  I also did `this.props.storyTextValueRedux(event.target.value);` and it still says undefined.  Maybe I should get rid of `this.setState({storyTextValue: event.target.storyTextValue});`?  I've been stuck on this for so long, I have no idea what do anymore haha.

Comment: what prints out if you type `console.log(event.target.value)` in handleSubmit? Is it the value you want?

Comment: Undefined gets printed out still which isn't what I want

Comment: ok you're `handleStoryText ` is already setting state so yes remove the setState from the handle submit... then do try dispatching the action with `this.state.value`... I just noticed you aren't initializing state in the component either... please do that... you will get a much better response if you present a codepen or something like that.

Comment: Ok I removed `this.setState({storyTextValue: event.target.storyTextValue});` and did  `this.props.storyTextValueRedux(this.state.value);`.  I also initialized  `this.state = {
            value: ''
        }`.  Now, I'm able to type in `textarea` with no problem but whenever I hit submit, the value is still undefined.

Comment: I'm trying to present a codepen but not sure how I would be able to do that.

Comment: ok ... if you `console.log(this.state.value)` before `this.props.storyTextValueRedux(this.state.value);` is it defined?

Comment: is you app wrapped in a provider with the store injected? 
`<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180802/discussion-between-sp92-and-joey-gough).